# Action of a loopspace on a fiber?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $F \to X \to Y$ be a fiber sequence. Then $\pi_1(Y)$ acts on any homotopy invariant of $F$. What are the obstructions to lifting this to an actual action $\Omega Y \times F \to F$ of the loop space $\Omega Y$ on $F$?

Comment: $\Omega Y$ always acts on $F$ up to homotopy. Is that enough?

Comment: @Tyrone I suppose what I'm asking is when there is a map of $H$-spaces $\Omega Y \to Map(F,F)$. If such a map always exists, I'm just surprised nobody has told me about it before!

Comment: The more general case of the path space of the base operating on the fibres is studies in Math. Z. 130, 207-233 (1973)  "Groupoid Operations and Fibre-Homotopy Equivalence. I"  by Philip R. Heath

Comment: I also mention "An introduction to homotopy theory via groupoids and universal constructions" 
PR Heath - 1978 - Queen's University

Comment: @tcamps, I am of course referring to the action discussed in, say, Arkowitz's 'Introduction to Homotopy Theory', section 4-3-4.5. Is this not what you are looking for?